# High volume warning, Android

Tags: audio

In Android 5.0 and up (from what I've noticed), unplugging a jack device triggers a "volume reset" that lowers the audio output volume. Upon increasing the volume, a `toast` message appears stating the risk of listening to music at high volumes.

Upon some research, this is as a result of EU regulation. I don't know if this affects US devices, but I would like to know how to prevent the "volume reset" behaviour, as I find it particularly frustrating.

Comment: You would have to root your device and install mods to get rid of this behavior

Comment: The device you are plugging in has poor electrical protection for plug insert/removal. Buy a better device & the 'bang' won't happen, therefore the reset won't happen. I just had to swap an old but expensive speaker setup [died of old age] for a new, cheap, one. I now get the 'bang' I didn't realise was even a possibility before :/

Comment: @LPChip I'm happy to, is it feasible to modify this pre-build? If I can remove this before compiling I can do it just once, rather than every time I re-image my phone.

Comment: If your phone is rooted already, then I'm sure you can install an .apk or suite that will allow you to do tweak your phone. But I'm not entirely sure. I usually install custom roms that come with this ability out of the box.